# Civilization 4: Vista installation has "install for all users" greyed out

Tags: civilization-4

I'm trying to install Civ4 on Windows Vista 32-bit. The version on the DVD is 1.00.00. When I run setup.exe and follow the prompts, the dialog with "Install for All Users" is greyed out.

How do I install for all users? This worked fine when the same machine was an XP machine.

Comment: Are there multiple user accounts on the machine, if not then that is probably the reason it is grayed out.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple user accounts on the machine. Even if there weren't, the installation process is different for a specific user installation; "Program Files" vs. "\Users\<username>\..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the game had previously been installed for a specific user and then uninstalled.

I worked around the problem by creating a new administrator account and used that to install the game. With that account the checkbox to install for all users was enabled and the game installed just fine. Once I was done, I deleted the temporary account.

Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Please remember to mark your question as answered when you can!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to right click the installer exe and "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Already running as administrator. I have also tried running the installer in XP compatibility mode.